# Crashes on link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading the "Agile Web Development with Rails 6" book, and I'm facing an issue from the beginning exercice.

The book says to generate a Say controller, with 2 methods: hello and goodbye. And then, we're asked to link those 2 views by using the "link_to" helper.

```
<h1>Goodbye!</h1>
<p>
​ <%=​ link_to ​'Hello', say_hello_path ​%>​
</p>
```

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
​<p>
 <%=​ link_to ​'Goodbye'​, say_goodbye_path ​%>​
</p>
```

```
class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    @time = Time.now
  end

  def goodbye
  end
end
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'say/hello'
  get 'say/goodbye'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

When I run this, it crashes on both views with this error (and I get the very same error with the goodbye template):

```
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting ')'
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting ')'
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting ')'
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting ')'
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting ')'
app/views/say/hello.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
```

When I run `rake routes`:

```
say_hello GET /say/hello(.:format) say#hello
say_goodbye GET /say/goodbye(.:format) say#goodbye
```

Obviously the routes do exist so the say_xxxx_path should work. I've another tutorial project such a pattern work as expected. Both projects run on Rails 6.0.3.2 / Ruby 2.7.0. The Gemfile of the 2 project is same.

I can't figure out what's wrong in there. I suspect something should be wrong in this project Rails stack, but I don't know how to check this.

Comment: The output is telling you there is a syntax error on line 6 of app/views/say/hello.html.erb. Can you share that whole file so we can see it?

Comment: I would recommend reading https://medium.com/@nerdplusdog/how-to-read-and-resolve-common-error-codes-in-ruby-9a3ae4bfb0db it seems like a good guide on how to read error messages so they seem less cryptic

Comment: @maxpleaner The error is hidden control characters and no amount of reading up about error messages would have solved this however good or wise that advice may be. Thought you might be interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is an error in your links
Try

```
<%= link_to 'Goodbye', say_goodbye_path %>
```

Can you spot the difference? No! Well neither can I but when I copied and pasted your code to my app I got the same error you are seeing.

Copy and paste that and see if it helps

I suspect your editor may be including hidden control characters. What editor are you using? I highly recommend Atom and developing under linux will make your life a whole lot simpler

If you don't get to the bottom of this you are going to have many hours of debugging problems that do not exist

No one has answered your question because there is no visible problem with your code

***UPDATE***

On further investigation deleting each character in turn and replacing it with the typed in code solved the problem, It seems that every space including the beginning of the line has a hidden controller character and I had to delete two characters to get rid of a single space so I can only conclude that your editor is seriously stuffed up

Comment: Wonderful @jamesc!! It works indeed. I now know where the problem comes from. I copied/pasted the code from the epub open in the macOs Books app. And this always adds some tricky stuff. Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time. I'll take more attention on such problems now.